# How do I call vbs file from Outlook

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

Here's what I have

```
strPath = "C:\Scripts\vba\gggg.vbs"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run Chr(34) & strPath & Chr(34), 1, True
```

I keep getting error on `strPath = "C:\Scripts\vba\gggg.vbs"`
[image]

Comment: *did not work* is an absolutely useless problem description unless you explain what *did not work* means. What **specific problem** are you having with the code you posted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Shell + Explorer.exe to open the vbs file...

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Shell "Explorer.exe ""C:\Temp\FileName.vbs""", 1
End Sub
```